# Protecting folder and its files

Tags: .htaccess, security

I wish to protect folder with core files of CMS and its sub folders and files from accessing via web, and I tried with .htaccess file with this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Problem I have is that I can protect that folder but some script from that folder or its sub folder then do not work good.

I also tried with this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 76.xx.xx.xx
```

In this case 76.xx.xx.xx is static IP of site. 
Is there any way to prevent accessing files in that folder but still to make all work ok?

**Another question.**

I wish to secure more my site from hackers. So, is there any way to prevent injecting malicious files and code in my scripts/files and/or to block my site of executing files from other sites, hosts, to allow just working with local files.

I prefer .htaccess file, but if it is needed I have access to WHM if there is need for editing other files (but in that case I will need step by step guide). I am running site on Linux VPS with Cent-OS 5 system.

Comment: which CMS do you use? Which files are you talking about? Is there a chance to modify the CMS to achieve your goal?

Comment: I use zenphoto from (www.zenphoto.org)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to put the accessible files in an apache-accessible directory, but all the rest into a directory out of the way from Apache. For example:

```
/usr/
  local/
    mycms/
      public/
      lib/
/var/
  www/
    mycms -> softlink to /usr/local/mycms/public
```

Or better yet, make mycms an alias in Apache config, pointing at the public directory. This way, the files that should be accessible are, those that shouldn't be aren't, and you can still reference all your other files simply by `../lib/` etc.

I know this does not really answer your question literally, and if the CMS directory structure is not under your control, this may not be the best way to do it.

Another way is through rewrites - simply rewrite *all* requests to your CMS directory except for your CMS's entry script into requests for the entry script.